# Stop Specific URLs in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, url, exception, webview

So I have made a very basic app in swift as a beginner with help from all over the internet. It's a webview and I've embedded a wordpress blog into it, however at the bottom of the page when the app loads there is a hyperlink to create your own blog. Now the user of the app must stay with the domain of my wordpress blog i.e. a url with https://"mywordpressblog".wordpress.com and not deviate to anything else. Now there are no other hyper links for it to deviate outside of the loop of wordpress, so is there a way of having an error message come up, if somebody tried to click on this link?

Comment: is it WKWebView or UIWebView ? iOS or OS X?

Comment: i started off using UIWebView, but changed to WKWebView because it integrated back wards and forwards swiping gesture

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231061/wkwebview-open-links-from-certain-domain-in-safari/36231713#36231713

Comment: you are a godsend i love you