# How to open Apple Map App on iOS App inside HTML

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, html

Now, I embed an HTML via `WKWebView`. If a user clicks the `a` element, I want to open the Apple Map APP. It seems nothing to happen, only the background color changed.
My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        a {
            display: block;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 100px auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>open the  apple map</h1>

<a href="maps:ll=38.897096,-77.036545" class="context-block-button map-button" id="map-button-1"><i class="ss-map icon-left"></i><span>Open in map (maps:)</span></a>

</body>
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('body').on('click','a',function () {
            $('body').css('background-color','blue');
      window.location.href = " http://maps.apple.com/?q=Mexican+Restaurant&sll=50.894967,4.341626&z=10&t=s";
    })
</script>
</html>
```

In the safari, I copy " http://maps.apple.com/?q=Mexican+Restaurant&sll=50.894967,4.341626&z=10&t=s".Then the safari will open the Apple App on Mac.

Must I use the `Swift4` API to open the Apple Map App?
One more thing, if the solution must change the `info.plist` or change the App target setting, thank you for writing this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use Swift API and need to implement WKNavigationDelegate, add decidePolicyForNavigationAction method.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36231713) from another thread.