# Detect change in WebView URL with Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, url

I'm creating a [hybrid app](https://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/) and I'm trying to pass some data from the WebView to the native app.

The best method I can think of to accomplish this is to use [URL variables](http://corymathews.com/understanding-url-variables/), and then add a listener to the URL in Swift to get the new data.

I'm able to get the URL variable from the WebView when it first loads with this Swift code...

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

   print(getQueryStringParameter(url: (webView.request?.url?.absoluteString)!, param: "id"));

}
func getQueryStringParameter(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
    guard let url = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
    return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
}
```

This works great, but I can't seem to find a WebView listener to detect when I add a new URL variable through JS at a later time after the page loads. Here is that JS...

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?id=mydata");
```

Any ideas how to listen for that in Swift? Or is there a better way to pass data from a web view to a native app?

Comment: You can make your view controller the delegate of your WKWebView Navigation, implement  the method `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {`, check the navigation type and the request url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36231713/2303865

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you are looking for this code.

You need to use WKWebView and implement the respective delegates.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("finish to load")
        if webView.url!.absoluteString.range(of: "ADD_STRING_TO_BE_CHECKED_HERE") != nil
        {
            print("Success")

            //DO WHAT YOU NEED HERE
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...