# When i click a link in my WKWebView Browser it goes to safari

Tags: ios, swift

How do i get my WKWebview browser to open links in the same browser, currently if i click a link it doesnt do anything and only lets me open it in safari. How can i fix this so that when a link is clicked it opens in the same WkWebView browser?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    //Web View
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://tweetdeck.twitter.com/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.load(request)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231061/wkwebview-open-links-from-certain-domain-in-safari

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code use decidePolicyFor method of WKNavigationDelegate

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }

        let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
        if components?.scheme == "http" || components?.scheme == "https"
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}}
```

Comment: it just brings me to safari, i want it to load in the browser that i clicked the link in @kishor soneji

Comment: I check your code by default is loaded in WKWebview @user12494754 when click on button also they reload same wkwebview

Comment: before adding your code, when i click the link it just did nothing @kishor soneji