# How to get headers from WKWbView finish loads

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am using `WKWebView` in app & i am looking for getting all headers from wkwebview in finish loads method `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {`  Just like in `UIWebView`

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("Finished loads---", webView.request?.allHTTPHeaderFields)
    }
```

How can we achieve that in `WKWebView` ?

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: I am not getting headers in `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!` @ElTomato

Comment: @ElTomato in `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!`  the code `webView.request?.allHTTPHeaderFields` doesn't works. Could you please help.

Comment: I don't think you can with didFinish.

Comment: @ElTomato i have break down the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403684/why-referer-appleapp-app-ios-header-not-displaying-in-wkwebview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your view controller as the WKWebView Navigation Delegate `WKNavigationDelegate` and implement its `decidePolicyFor` method:

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

Try like this:

---

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    let allHTTPHeaderFields = navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
    for (key, value) in allHTTPHeaderFields {
        print("key:", key, "value:", value)
    }
    
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
            let host = url.host, !host.hasPrefix("www.google.com"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            print(url)
            print("Redirected to browser. No need to open it locally")
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            print("Open it locally")
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    } else {
        print("not a user click")
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the app crash if you don't set `decisionHandler(.allow)` or `decisionHandler(.cancel)`?

Comment: @LeoDabus @ElTomato Thanks But. if URL has multiple redirection then it doesn't captured in `decidePolicyFor navigationAction` It only shows very first URL

Comment: @Amit what do you want to do? It all depends how you are deciding which navigation you want to allow or not https://stackoverflow.com/a/36231713/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus. somehow we need to manage in `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` which calls on every redirections so we can confirm that on every redirection headers are embedding correctly. :) This is i am looking for

Comment: @Amit not sure what are you asking. In your question you asked how to get the headers only when it finishes loading the web view. Is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes @LeoDabus I Agree with your answer. But let say for example i have typed "Leo" in browser it will open search results now the on print statement  Referer has changed `"Referer": "https://www.google.com/"`

Comment: @LeoDabus i have posted new question for referrer persist  issue .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404439/persist-referer-header-in-ios-wkwebview

Answer (score 1):

Use `WKWebView`'s `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    
    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let urlStr = "https://www.google.com/"
        if let url = URL(string: urlStr) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
            //webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
            //webView.navigationDelegate = self
        }
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        let request = navigationAction.request
        if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.host {
            if host == "www.google.com" {
                if let headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields {
                    print("Google Headers: \(headers)")
                } else {
                    print("Nope, sir")
                }
            }
            else if host == "www.apple.com" {
                if let headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields {
                    print("Apple Headers: \(headers)")
                } else {
                    print("Nope, sir")
                }
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

And I get the following.

> ["User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)", "Accept":
> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"]
> Headers: ["Accept-Language": "en-us", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":
> "1", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "User-Agent":
> "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)", "Accept":
> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"]

Comment: beat you by 30 seconds :)

Comment: Yes, you did, sir.

Comment: No worries :) Good answers by Both legends :)

Comment: @ElTomato i have added comments on another answers please help with it.

Comment: @ElTomato i have posted new question for referrer persist issue .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404439/persist-referer-header-in-ios-wkwebview