# Persist “Referer” header in iOS WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am passing custom headers in WKWebView. But on redirection Headers get updated with new ones.
for example i have typed "MyName" in browser it will open search results now the on print statement Referer has changed "Referer": "https://www.google.com/"
How to persist custom headers across the redirections.

In  `WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction` function headers get updated on redirection.

`navigationAction.request.setValue("/App/app/iOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")` That doesn't works

```
import WebKit

class WKWEBViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    private var wkWebView: WKWebView!
    var loadURLString = "https://www.google.com"
    
    var customHeaders:[String:String] = ["Referer":"/AppleApp/app/iOS"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        loadURL()
    }
    
    private func loadURL() {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: config)
        wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        wkWebView.backgroundColor = .white
        wkWebView.scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(wkWebView)
        
        if let pdfurl = URL(string: loadURLString) {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: pdfurl)
            if customHeaders.count != 0 {
                for obj in customHeaders {
                    urlRequest.addValue(obj.value, forHTTPHeaderField: obj.key)
                }
            }
            wkWebView.load(urlRequest)
        }
    }
}

extension WKWEBViewController {
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        let request = navigationAction.request
        print("URl--->", request.url)
        if let headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields {
            print("Headers: \(headers)")
        } else {
            print("Nope, sir")
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those customer headers?

Comment: Before `var customHeaders:[String:String] = ["Referer":"/AppleApp/app/iOS"]` After   `"Referer": "https://www.google.com/"` @ElTomato

Answer (score 0):

Like the following?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    
    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let urlStr = "https://www.google.com/"
        if let url = URL(string: urlStr) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        var request = navigationAction.request
        if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.host {
            if host == "www.google.com" {
                request.setValue("https://www.google.com/", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
                if let headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields {
                    print("Google Headers: \(headers)")
                }
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

The following is the result

> Google Headers: ["Referer": "https://www.google.com/", "User-Agent":
> "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)", "Accept":
> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"]

Comment: But you are not assigning headers to `navigationAction` & in `WKWebView`

Comment: I see.  I don't know if you can do that.

Comment: I tried `navigationAction.request.setValue("/App/app/iOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")` That doesn't works